# How to Check if a class extends another

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, methods

I have seen variants of this question but none of them really address my problem.

Lets say I am building an army with classes. At the top of my Inheritance structure I have an abstract "**Unit**" class. Then an abstract "**Flying**", "**Ground**" and "**Building**" class that extends unit. Then a concrete "**Helicopter**" and "**Jet**" class that extends Flying. As well as a concrete "**Soldier**" and "**Tank**" class that extends Ground. and finally a "**HQ**" and "**Supply**" that extends building.

The following is a method under the "**Soldier**" Class:

```
public void attack(Unit enemy){
if(enemy.getSuperclass().equals(Flying)){
    System.out.print("Soldiers cant attack flying units");
}
else{
    //Code to attack enemy here
}
```

I want *enemy* to be any form of unit. This is because a soldier should be able to attack both buildings and other ground units, However I don't want the Soldiers to be able to attack flying objects.

The obvious problem is that because I declared *enemy* as a **Unit**, it doesn't know which subclass it belongs to and therefore is trying to find a SuperClass for Unit which doesn't exist.

I'm sure I could have a getter for every unit which has manually set what type of unit it is... but that is more work and doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Wow, 5 equivalent answers published in the same 10-second time slice!

Comment: You might also use interfaces, as class inheritance might be to restrictive to model all. But first trying inheritance is fine.

Comment: *instanceof* amazement !

Comment: I would sugest to implement the attack method in Flying, Ground and Building class, and overload, implementing a method for every possible kind of attack: for example in Flying class `attack(Flying enemy)` `attack(Groung enemy)` `attack(Building enemy)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```
if(enemy.getSuperclass().equals(Flying)){
```

to

```
if(enemy instanceof Flying){
```

That will check if `enemy` is an instance of any of the classes that derive from `Flying`, rather than checking *specifically* for the `Flying` class (which we know `enemy` won't be, as `Flying` is abstract).

`instanceof` is quite handy, but whenever I use it (and I sometimes do), I step back and look at my structure in hopes that I can find some way to refactor to avoid it (perhaps things that can be attacked by soldiers have some common characteristic and could implement an abstract `Unit` sub-class — `GroundBased` or something — which you could use for the argument instead of `Unit`). You may not be able to in this case, but it's worth double-checking.

Comment: Rethinking the class design is a good advice. A good way might also be to use an interface and implement the common parts in a subclass Unit. With an interface you don't have to worry that a class is derived from a particular implementation of another class but you still can make sure that the bevhiour is the same.

Comment: yes but an interface wont let me create cookie cutter methods to apply to the concrete classes below it. I would have to re-create the method for every unit. Unless I don't understand interfaces correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15919_01/wlp.1032/e14255/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) operator.

```
    if(enemy instanceof Flying){
        System.out.print("Soldiers cant attack flying units");
    }
    else{
        attack(enemy);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use instanceof for this. This also works i.e. for interfaces.

Take also care that the variable may not be null when using instanceof.

class B extends A

```
   public class test
   {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new B();
        if(a instanceof A)
            System.out.println("B derived from A");
        if(b instanceof A)
            System.out.println("B derived from A");
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (enemy instanceof Flying)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
if (enemy instanceof Flying)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(enemy instanceof Flying) {}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a design smell. The fundamental requirement is a job for the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) but you should also be looking to use polymorphism better than this before you even get to the Visitor.